# Grafana - Alert only after some minutes

Tags: grafana

i configured grafana alert to have an email after 10 minutes of CPU overload, instead alert start immediately when the event occurs

[image]

it's correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`last()` will only use the last value of a series. Ex `[ 10, 20, 20, 10, 100 ]` will return `100`.

If you only want to trigger the alert when cpu have been above 90 for 10m then you need to use `min()` instead. Which will only return a value above 90 once all values in the last 10m are above 90.

Comment: Once this PR is merged https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/13947 It will be possible to configure an duration for while an alert have to be violating the threshold before changing state to alerting